# MongoDB - searching text

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, text-search

What is the best strategy for selecting mongodb entries in which a string value contains a set of words or phrases?  I'm thinking of something equivalent to mysql's LIKE function, e.g.

```
    WHERE (TEXT LIKE "% apple %") or (TEXT LIKE "% banana %")
```

I've seen options that involve tokenizing the string, but this would involve building unigrams for all the text, which would be huge no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB has no full text search capability right now, but it's easy to use external search engines like SOLR.

I strongly discourage you trying to rebuild text search with Regex or word stemming etc. yourself. You should rather focus on your app own features :)

I am using this combination: [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/), [Sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/) and [Mongoid-Sunspot](https://github.com/jugyo/sunspot_mongoid). It works very well in production, and development setup is easy.

Comment: +1 for this - and I would also recommend voting this up (it's already number 2, but all votes help): https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-380

Answer (score 4):

Mongo now supports text search since 2.4.
My experience has been pretty positive

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/text-search/

You start the server with setParameter text search enabled
Then enable the index on the collection
Then search with runCommand

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression support in MongoDB queries. More details available @ the following link

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/

Here are two examples should the above link move again in the future:

```
db.collection.find( { field: /acme.*corp/i } );
db.collection.find( { field: { $regex: 'acme.*corp', $options: 'i' } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow MongoDB built-in text search failed to meet my requirements on an existing database which used a compound index. I am now using [mongoose-search-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-search-plugin) and it has been working superbly well. It uses natural stemming, and distance algorithms to return a relevance score.

```
User.search('Malaysia Car Food',{username:1},{},  function(err, u){
   console.log('Search Results: '+JSON.stringify(u));
});
```